# Is it safe to fread 0 bytes into a NULL-pointer?

Tags: c, null, language-lawyer, fread

In my environment, the following code runs fine, but is it guaranteed to be okay?

```
FILE *file = fopen("in", "r");
int *read_to = NULL;
size_t count = 0;
size_t read = fread(read_to, sizeof(*read_to), count, file);
fclose(file);
```

respectively

```
FILE *file = fopen("out", "w");
int *write = NULL;
size_t count = 0;
size_t written = fwrite(write, sizeof(*write), count, file);
fclose(file);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not guaranteed to work, and a strict reading of the Standard leads to the conclusion that passing a null pointer as the first argument to `fread()` or `fwrite()` causes undefined behavior.

According to [§7.21.8.1 ¶2 of the C11 Draft Standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.8.1p2):

> **size_t fread(void * restrict ptr,
>                 size_t size, size_t nmemb,
>                 FILE * restrict stream);**
>
> The **fread** function reads, into the array pointed to by **ptr**....

Similarly, in [§7.21.8.2 ¶2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.8.2p2):

> **size_t fwrite(const void * restrict ptr,
>                 size_t size, size_t nmemb,
>                 FILE * restrict stream);**
>
> The **fwrite** function writes, from the array pointed to by **ptr**....

But, in the section describing the use of library functions [(§7.1.4)](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4p1) it is stated that:

> If an argument to a function has an invalid value (such as a value outside the domain of the function, or a pointer outside the address space of the program, or a null pointer, or a pointer to non-modifiable storage when the corresponding parameter is not const-qualified) or a type (after promotion) not expected by a function with variable number of arguments, the behavior is undefined. **If a function argument is described as being an array, the pointer actually passed to the function shall have a value such that all address computations and accesses to objects (that would be valid if the pointer did point to the first element of such an array) are in fact valid.**

Finally, in [§4 ¶2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#4p2):

> If a ''shall'' or ''shall not'' requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime- constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined.

Since a null pointer does not point to a valid object, address computations and accesses are not valid on null pointers, thus passing a null pointer to `fread()` or `fwrite()` violates the "shall" of §7.1.4, so the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

"N1570 Committee Draft — April 12, 2011 ISO/IEC 9899:201x" says in 7.21.8

> If size or nmemb is zero,
>   fread returns zero and the contents of the array and the state of the stream remain
>   unchanged.

and

> If size or nmemb is zero,
>   fwrite returns zero and the state of the stream remains unchanged.

Based on the above text I would expect it to be valid.

Comment: These statements only say that the functions will work if the length is zero, not if the pointer is null. Per statements in the preceding paragraphs, which specifies constraints, the `ptr` parameter points to an array. If called with a null pointer, then `ptr` does not point to an array, so technically this violates the constraint. Certainly a straightforward implementation of `fread` and `fwrite` likely will not care if `ptr` is null when the length is zero, but the question asks if it is **guaranteed**.

Answer (score -1):

Whether the behavior is undefined depends upon whether a null argument would be regarded as "invalid".  The description of the behavior above *fully describes* the behavior of `fread` and `fwrite` when the size is zero, in a way that ignores the data pointer: the function of `fread(anything, 0,0, anything)` is to return zero with no side-effects--an action which it should be possible to carry out without even looking at the passed-in pointers.

The only danger is that some compiler writers may not recognize the "such as" language in 7.1.4 as providing examples of things that an erroneous program might pass in ways that would request that a function perform an "impossible" action (like read or write bytes of data from a null address, or dereference a null pointer or write to const-qualified storage), but instead treat the list as a normative spec indicating that such arguments are invalid *even in contexts where they would naturally be ignored*.  While it is doubtful that the latter treatment would offer any meaningful performance benefit outside of contrived scenarios, compiler writers who think "clever" and "stupid" are antonyms might use the latter treatment to justify "optimizations".

Quality implementations will treat fread(any,0,0,file) as a no-op without regard for whether the data pointer is null, since doing so will offer some benefit at zero cost.

As to whether code which uses fwrite to write various data, including an optional chunk identified by combination of a pointer+size_t, and which documents to its caller that (null+0) is a valid way of indicating no optional data, should use special handling for the size-zero case, I guess that depends upon whether one's code is going to be processed by quality compilers or "clever" ones.

Comment: Speaking of null+0, I think pointer arithmetic on a null pointer is UB even if it's just adding 0, and I would be unsurprised to find even a "quality" `fread` implementation computing `read_to+sizeof(*read_to)*count` when `count` is 0.

Comment: @user2357112: The behavior of adding 0 to a null pointer is defined in C++ (it yields a null pointer).  The C Standard would *allow* implementations to behave in arbitrary fashion when adding 0 to null, and there are some platforms where that might be a natural behavior, but the doesn't mean that quality implementations shouldn't treat `ptr+0` as yielding `ptr` for all pointer values where that would be the natural platform behavior.

Comment: @user2357112: What people fail to realize is that, judging from the C89 rationale, the authors of C89 didn't think the Standard needed to mandate all the things *that compilers were already doing anyway*.  They expected that compiler writers would recognize that if a particular idiom is popular among programs on a particular platform and field, quality implementations targeting that platform and field would support it whether the Standard mandated it or not.  If the Standard made any effort to allow programmers to do everything that is possible with "popular extensions", but without having...

Comment: ...to use UB (if nothing else, by `#ifndef ZERO_SIZE_FREAD_ALWAYS_NOP`/`#error SORRY`/`#endif`), then it might be reasonable to interpret the Standard narrowly.  Otherwise, I would question why anyone should be more interested in whether a jumping the rails in some situation  would be "conforming" than in whether it would make a compiler less *useful*.